# How do I stop my rabbit from peeing on my bed?

Tags: behavior, rabbits, toilet-training, territory

I have a 2 year old spayed rabbit that reliably uses her litter box, with the exception of occasionally peeing on my bed. It seems to happen when she's looking for attention and I don't give it to her. I wash everything when she does this and she continued the habit even after I moved to a new place with a new bed, sheets, mattress, etc., so I don't think it's because there is a leftover scent. How do I get her to stop doing this?

Comment: Please look at this question: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/23250/bunny-pees-on-bed You could search for tags like this: [toilet-training][rabbits] Then you get a lots of questions for this theme and a lots of answers too :)